# Bind9 forward specific zone to another server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

I'm trying to set up 2 DNS servers on ubuntu to avoid poisoning for specific domains. I've configured 3 servers as forwarders for all non-specific domain names and added zones(like speedtest.net) with Google's DNS as forwarders. But when I test using nslookup, I can see my server is still using those 3 servers from the logs. I'm testing on the slave server,both .

Here's my options:

```
//========================================================================
dnssec-validation no;

listen-on-v6 { any; };
// My main name server
forwarders {
    223.5.5.5;
    223.6.6.6;
    202.106.0.20;
    };
recursion yes;
    //allow-recursion {
//  any;
//  };
dnssec-enable yes;
    allow-query     { any; };
statistics-file "/var/log/named/stats";
forward only;
dnssec-lookaside . trust-anchor dlv.isc.org.;};
```

Here's one of my zone that I want to forward to Google's DNS:

```
zone "speedtest.net" {
type forward;
forward only;
forwarders {
    8.8.8.8;
    };
//
};
```

Logs when I test beta.speedtest.net using nslookup:

`24-Mar-2016 11:19:58.208 decrement_reference: delete from rbt: 0x7fd94fd74880 verycdn.net
24-Mar-2016 11:20:10.735 error (FORMERR) resolving 'cs62.adn.edgecastcdn.net/AAAA/IN': 223.6.6.6#53
24-Mar-2016 11:20:10.751 error (FORMERR) resolving 'cs62.adn.edgecastcdn.net/AAAA/IN': 223.5.5.5#53
24-Mar-2016 11:20:10.766 error (FORMERR) resolving 'cs62.adn.edgecastcdn.net/AAAA/IN': 202.106.0.20#53
24-Mar-2016 11:20:10.766 client 103.20.34.1#54897 (beta.speedtest.net): query failed (SERVFAIL) for beta.speedtest.net/IN/AAAA at query.c:7004`

It's still using